# Trying to turn an array into a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a problem with my function that turns data from an array into a list in different component.
I think the problem is with my lack of understanding where to put `document.GetElementById().`
I get error `document.getElementById(...) is null`.
Is it because I try to access specific location before it is rendered? Then how should I access it, maybe it has something to do with component lifecycle? Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Day from "./day";
import image1 from "./img/eggs.jpg";

class Stuff extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.makeList = this.makeList.bind(this);
  }

     makeList(array) {
      var list = document.createElement('ul');
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          var item = document.createElement('li');
          item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));
          list.appendChild(item);
      }
      return list;
  }

  render() {
    const source =  {
        breakfast: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "eggs",
            img: image1,
            description: "Start a day with delicious and nutricious eggs!",
            ingridients: ['2 eggs', 'two slices of toast', 'bacon', 'butter']
          },
          ...
        ]}

    return (
      <div>
        <Day {...source}
             makeList={this.makeList} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Stuff;
```

and Day component where React turn an error:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./day.css";

class Day extends Component {

  render() {
    const appChild = document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(this.props.makeList(this.props.source.breakfast.ingridients));
    return (
        <div className="displayOne">
          <img src= {this.props.breakfast[0].img} alt="eggs" />
          <h3>{this.props.breakfast[0].description}</h3>
          <div id="foo">
          <p>{appChild}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Day;
```

Thank you for help and understanding!

Comment: Why are you both using JSX and doing direct DOM creation?

Comment: You are right. I really don't know it is my first full website I am making and did not think it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably should use jsx instead of manipulating the dom directly:

```
function makeList(array) {
    return (
        <ul>
            (array.map((value, index) => (<li>{value}</li>)
        </ul>
    )
}
```

or a full, more optimal, solution would be to create a `Breakfast` component:

```js
class Stuff extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.source = {
            breakfast: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "eggs",
                    img: image1,
                    description: "Start a day with delicious and nutricious eggs!",
                    ingridients: ['2 eggs', 'two slices of toast', 'bacon', 'butter']
                },
            ]
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Day source={this.source}></Day>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Day extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="displayOne">
                {this.props.source.breakfast.map((breakfast) => <Breakfast breakfast={breakfast}/>)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function Breakfast({breakfast}) {
    return (
        <div className="displayOne">
            <img src={breakfast.img} alt="eggs"/>
            <h3>{breakfast.description}</h3>
            <ul>
                {breakfast.ingridients.map((ingridient) => <li>{ingridient}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In generall, if you haven't done already. I would advice you to go through the "Getting Started" guide of React to understand the "way of react".
Here is the official "Intro to React": https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Naturally it will work but I wanted to make an array with objects: Breakfast, dinner and supper and 3 different divs one under another that will display data from these objects and arrows on the right and left site which will switch between recipes. I'm still new to web developement i only read 1 book and took courses on codecademy so there is still a lot of confusion.